# Chrome 61: Local Storage Location Changed?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

Since upgrading to Chrome 61, new local storage files are no longer created in...

%localappdata%\google\chrome\user data\default\local storage\

Any ideas where local storage is now held in the latest Chrome update?

Comment: Have you search your hdd for the folder?

Comment: Done a full search, but nothing which matches the previous file within local storage that we use. And from Chrome advanced settings we can see that the entry has been created, so it should be present somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**James Amos**, you'll right, new place location storage is *.ldb file.
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb
see also the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325138/local-storage-with-chrome-61